# Updating the firmware an Ender 3 With Linux

Tags: creality-ender-3, firmware

I have the following command:

`format /q H:/fs:fat32/a:4096`

that will then allow me to upload a .bin file that will update the ender's firmware.  How do I do this same format on linux?

(It seems the Ender does not respond to firmware update now, even if I leave it as the only file on the drive.  What is the Ender really looking for?)

I have a stock board.

Comment: Someone else might correct me if I am wrong, but that command only formats the SD card for use with the 3D printer. It has nothing to do with the firmware itself.

Comment: I know that.  But strangely, without it the Ender seems to ignore the firmware.

Comment: Correct. If the SD card is not formatted in the way the printer requires then it won't be able to read the information on the SD card. Please [edit] your question to explain what exactly you are having problems with.

Answer (score 1):

It's not obvious which, if either, the question is asking:

- How does this Microsoft gobbledygook translate into a normal Linux command.
- This is how I'd normally do it, but what would it be if I have to do it on Linux?

`format /q H:/fs:fat32/a:4096` is a lazy way of saying
`format  H:  /q  /fs:fat32  /a:4096`.

The documentation says:

```
>format /?
Formats a disk for use with Windows.

FORMAT volume [/FS:file-system] [/V:label] [/Q] [/L[:state]] [/A:size]
              [/C] [/I:state] [/X] [/P:passes] [/S:state]
…
  volume          Specifies the drive letter (followed by a colon),
                  mount point, or volume name.
  /FS:filesystem  Specifies the type of the file system (FAT, FAT32, exFAT,
                  NTFS, UDF, ReFS).
  /A:size         Overrides the default allocation unit size. Default settings
                  are strongly recommended for general use.
                  …
  /Q              Performs a quick format. Note that this switch overrides /P.
  …
```

Linux has formatting commands named mkfs.*

```
$ mkfs.fat -help
mkfs.fat 4.1 (2017-01-24)
Usage: mkfs.fat [-a][-A][-c][-C][-v][-I][-l bad-block-file]
   [-b backup-boot-sector]
   [-m boot-msg-file][-n volume-name][-i volume-id]
   [-s sectors-per-cluster][-S logical-sector-size][-f number-of-FATs]
   [-h hidden-sectors][-F fat-size][-r root-dir-entries][-R reserved-sectors]
   [-M FAT-media-byte][-D drive_number]
   [--invariant]
   [--help]
   /dev/name [blocks]
```

`man mkfs.fat` gives details about the individual options.